# AWS Cloud Formation Elastic Load Balancing Account ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a template with cloud formation that sets up a load balancer that writes logs to S3 bucket. Instead of giving full access to everyone (e.g. *), I want to restrict `PutObject` access to only the load balancer account or service:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "LoggingBucketPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Bucket": {
          "Ref": "LoggingBucket"
        },
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:aws:s3:::",
                {
                  "Ref": "LoggingBucket"
                },
                "/*"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "Principal": {
            "Ref": "ElasticLoadBalancingAccountID" //How do I set this dynamically?
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-access-logs.html#attach-bucket-policy) provides account ID's of ELB instances in various regions. However, the template I'm creating has a availability zone parameter where the user can chose a availability zone to deploy the stack to. So what I would ideally like to do is have some sort of `ref` variable in my bucket policy that gets the account id of load balancer based on the availability zone.

I also looked at examples in the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html), but the one example that does use `Ref`, doesn't really define the variable.

How do I achieve this?

**Edit**: I meant the availability zones instead of region. The input parameter provides the user with a drop down of availability zones in a region.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. Its not really dynamic, but better than just hardcoding the id directly. As per [this Amazon re-invent presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/dvo304-aws-cloudformation-best-practices), the proper way is to first define a mapping:

```
{
  "Mappings": {
    "RegionalConfigs": {
      "us-east-1": {
        "AMI": "",
        "ELBAccountId": "127311923021",
        "ArnPrefix": "arn:aws:"
      },
      "us-west-1": {
        "AMI": "",
        "ELBAccountId": "027434742980",
        "ArnPrefix": "arn:aws:"
      },
      "us-west-2": {
        "AMI": "",
        "ELBAccountId": "797873946194",
        "ArnPrefix": "arn:aws:"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then use it in a policy:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "LoggingBucketPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "",
          "Resource": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                {
                  "Fn::FindInMap": [
                    "RegionalConfigs",
                    {
                      "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                    },
                    "ArnPrefix"
                  ]
                },
                "s3:::",
                {
                  "Ref": "LoggingBucket"
                },
                "/",
                "Logs",
                "/AWSLogs/",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                },
                "/*"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": {
              "Fn::FindInMap": [
                "RegionalConfigs",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "ELBAccountId"
              ]
            }
          },
          "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject"
          ]
        },
        "Bucket": {
          "Ref": "LoggingBucket"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html Thanks for suggesting this solution. The "PolicyDocument" section listed is invalid however. It does not contain a "Statement" block. After "PolicyDocument" there should be a "Statement" section that looks like this:  "Statement" : [
                        { //policy statement// } ]

Comment: If that can help someone I have created this gist: https://gist.github.com/Yanal-Yves/ed6244326f521fb5d7e051447275da41 with all the ELB account ids of the currently 25 regions available.

Answer (score 4):

There's no variable that includes the ELB account IDs. Those are AWS's various account identifiers.

To include them in your policy, you have to either:

1. hard code those account IDs,
2. use input variables into your template for them, or
3. try using a CloudFormation "map" to setup a map of region-to-account-id list, then select the appropriate list using the `AWS::Region` variable.

Comment: Hi..thank you for the response. I mean availability zone instead of the region. I tried your suggestion but I get an error: `Access Denied for bucket: xxxxxxxxxxx.development. Please check S3bucket permission`

Comment: I created an output variable to dump the value of `{"Ref":"AWS::AccountId"} and turns out that it writes the value of my account id..the account thats used to create the stack and *not* the account id thats used to run ELB as identified here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-access-logs.html#enable-access-logs-console

Comment: OK. I understand what you're trying to do. There's no variable for what you want. You have to either hard code those account IDs, or use input variables into your template for them.